# Chart getting duplicated everytime the component rerenders - Sunburst-chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, react-hooks

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/sunburst-chart in my react app and calling its chart method inside useEffect with data and also passing the data variable in the dependency array. Initially, its rendering properly. But, whenever, the data get updated, instead of the updating the chart, its creating new chart on every useEffect call. How can I solve this chart duplicating and instead of it, I need the chart to get updated.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import Sunburst from 'sunburst-chart'
import * as d3 from 'd3'

const SunburstChart = ({ data }) => {
  const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemePaired)

  useEffect(() => {
      Sunburst()
        .data(data)
        .width(740)
        .height(740)
        .sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value)
        .color((d) => color(d.name))
        .excludeRoot(true)(document.getElementById('chart-sunburst'))
    }
  }, [data])

  return (
    <div id="chart-container">
      <div id="chart-sunburst"></div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SunburstChart
```

you can find the implementation here - https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-feather-jz5upc?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the sunburst chart with kapsule seems to fix the duplication. Refer to my answer on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78162806/18864894)